# JAVA/OOM: How to dump all information on java heap space when it crashes due to OOM?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

I am a newbie on JAVA.
I run a program on top of distributed framework implemented in JAVA.

When I use large data, the program crashes due to OutOfMemory with some error stacks. But the error stacks do not contain the information that I am looking for.

I want to check what kinds of data structures (java objects) were consuming the heap space at the time when it crashed.

Is there any well-known tricks, methods, or tools for it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and `HeapDumpPath` options to generate a heap dump when an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs in the JVM.

For example:

`$ java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/path MyApp`

If you suspect a memory leak, you can use `jmap`, which is included with the JDK, to produce a heap dump of your application *while it's running*.

For example:

`jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=dump.hprof <pid>`

You can then analyze `dump.hprof` using an application such as YourKit to pinpoint what code is causing the leak.

**References**

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html

Comment: Thanks, which tool should I use the generated heap dump files?

Comment: Use `jmap` as I described above.  Note: the `live` option will cause a full GC cycle.  If this is a production application and that worries you, remove this option.